# How can I know how many groups I will get using regex?

Tags: java, regex

Lets say that i'm getting a text and I need to have some regex on it which goes as follows:

```
String aContent = " title='111' title='222' ";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s{1,}(title=){1}+(.){1,}'{1}"); 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(aTagContent);
```

And the data is being found/matched by using `find()`

How can I know how many groups I assume to get from this regex? 
I know that there is `matcher.groupCount()` so this is not the answer i'm looking for.

What i'm actully asking is:

- How this text will be splitted? how can I know that without using `matcher.groupCount()` ?

Comment: To know that you need to have prior knowledge of your input. Otherwise, you can't.

Comment: That's for sure, but there is some sample in the question, please answer by that if you can

Comment: i can't able to understand your question. `groupcount` method is used to get the group counts.

Comment: ok, but if I know the text in advanced, how can I know the result? My big question, how does the text is being splitted ?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/lU4oT6/6 . Where splitting occurs?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.. If you know what goes in and what you're looking for, then you already know the answer.

Comment: Avoid using `{1,}`, `+` is clearer. Also `{1}` is redundant, it just makes your regex harder to read.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, that's was helpful, please put it as an answer

Comment: to do a non-greedy match https://regex101.com/r/lU4oT6/7

Comment: @a_z Ahh, sorry i can't. I just put your regex into that site. Say thanks to regex101... Stiil I can't able to understand your question..

Comment: You can mention that this site is good for these cases

Comment: Answer should answer question, not just give link to tool or resources. Problem here is that is hard to answer your question because question is very unclear. Consider [edit]ting your post to add examples of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Matcher.groupCount()` returns the number of groups in your `Pattern`, not in the result.

`Matcher.matches()` tries to match the entire input string against your pattern, `Matcher.find()` will sequentially try to match only part of your input string. The latter typically being used in a `while`-loop, so there's no prior knowledge about the amount of matches.

You can remove the trivial `{1}` quantifier, it makes your pattern overly verbose. Also, `{1,}` can be replaced by `+`. The first quote is missing from your pattern so it won't match your input string. Maybe something like this works for you:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+(title)='([^']+)'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(" title='111' title='222' ");

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("attribute: " + matcher.group(1) + ", value: " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Can you consider using `String.split("\\s")` first and iterate over the returned String array? At least you'll know the number of attribute-value pairs in advance.